# I want to change the background color of panel by choosing the colors from dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am writing code which lets user to choose the color of background of page(drop down list) and the problem is that i got the known colors from library System.Drawing and i don't know how to get that values from list. how i can do it?

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            string[] colorArray = Enum.GetNames(typeof(KnownColor));
            drpBack.DataSource = colorArray;
            drpBack.DataBind();}
```

// page load where i took the names of colors;

//Here is the button update

```
protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
        string back = drpBack.Text;
        Color style = (Color)Enum.Parse(typeof(Color), back);
        pnlCard.BackColor = style;}
```

When i click button update it gives me error : Type provided must be an Enum.

I tried to write instead of Color - KnownColor it gave me message: Can not implicitly convert type "KnownColor" to "Color"

Comment: [Multi-color DropDownList using C#](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19356/Multi-color-DropDownList-using-C) {not tested}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should parse the input back to `KnownColor`. Then you can create a `Color` from this value using [`Color.FromKnownColor()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.color.fromknowncolor?view=netframework-4.8):

```
protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
        string back = drpBack.Text;
        var parsedColor = (KnownColor)Enum.Parse(typeof(KnownColor), back);
        var style = Color.FromKnownColor(parsedColor);
        pnlCard.BackColor = style;
}
```